# Fourier integral for field propagation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, laser, fourier-transform, maxwell-equations

I am trying to calculate the pulse propagation in a linear medium, and I am having difficulty some calculation involve in Fourier transformation.

For example of the first order approximation of frequency, I can solve like

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \text{E}(Z,\Delta +w) \exp \left(-i \Delta  \left(t-\frac{Z \left(w* n'(w)+n(w)\right)}{c}\right)\right) \, d\Delta \, .$$

This becomes

$$\text{E}(0,t-(n(w)+w n'(w))\frac{Z}{c})$$

because the previous equation is a Fourier integral (delta function). However, I want to expand this to second order or frequency component

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \text{E}(Z,\Delta +w) \exp \left(-i \Delta  \left(t-\frac{Z \left(w* n'(w)+n(w)\right)}{c} \right)+i \Delta^2 (n'(w)+\frac{1}{2} w n''(w))\right) \, d\Delta$$

$\Delta$ become second order; I am not sure how to solve this integral. From the textbook, it should give me a attenuation and distortion of the pulse shape as it propagate. Any suggestion for how to solve this equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it has an analytical solution for every $E(z,t)$ you'll substitute.

However, I have seen some books assuming a Gaussian wave packet and solving that gives you a Gaussian wave packet that gets broader and broader the more it travels in the medium (and with less peak intensity - you can argue that from the conservation of energy).

Furthermore, this is a result you can understand with no math at all - the pulse becomes a new pulse with different phase for every $\omega$ (and it isn't linear with $\omega$ , ruining the transform-limited pulse and making it broad and with lower peak intensity.

I hope this helped!